# Populate select option onchange event

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want populate select field in wizard on every @api.onchange('journal_id')

My example:

```
    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('journal_id')
    def _populate(self):
        lst = []
        journals = self.env['account.move'].search([('journal_id','=',self.journal_id.id)])

        for journal in journals:
            lst.append((journal.id, journal.name))
        return lst


    journal_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal', 'Jornal', required=True)
    journal_from = fields.Selection('_populate',string='Name')
```

After change journal_id in console get good result but can't bind select field.

Where is problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('journal_id')
    def _populate(self):
        lst = []
        journals = self.env['account.move'].search([('journal_id','=',self.journal_id.id)])

        for journal in journals:
            key = '{}'.format(journal.id)
            value = '{}'.format(journal.name)
            lst.append((key, value))
        return lst
```

Comment: not working for me, empty select option again...in conslole looks good.